# Updating QListWidget when edited QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

I must make something like this:

We've got 2 elements: 

 1 - `QLineEdit` 

 2 - `QListWidget` filled with data

And I try to do: when You type something in `QLineEdit`, in `QListWidget` data are updated and displayed only this what fit to entered text in `QLineEdit`.

I don't have any idea how to make something like this, pleas help me.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want a filter. This is best done by a model/view approach using `QSortFilterProxyModel`.